# Problem with mAT30 ATU and FT-450D transceiver

Tags: transceiver, yaesu, antenna-tuner

Does [this tuner](http://www.mat-tuner.com/en/mAT-30.php) work with this transceiver? Would appreciate response as I cannot get it to work!

Comment: can you try to actually describe what you're doing, what happens, what you expected to happen (and how that differs)?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: The manual says that the mAT-030 works with the FT-450D.  Did you go into the radio's settings to tell it that an external autotuner is connected?  Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

yes went into external autotuner program on the FT450D, my problem was not leaving the buttons depressed for long enough!! managed to tune 1-1.5 on 20m but 1-4 on other bands--time to scrap the antenna and erect something that works! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction G4DIC.